# MySQL Add not picking up one field

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am doing a project to add, update, delete, etc records from a p2pmyadmin database.

I am working on the current code. When update is hit, all the fields update in the database, except the 'Surname' field. I cannot figure out why... Can anyone advise?

```
$dirtyPassword = $_POST['frmPassword1'];

if (isset($_POST['formName']) && $_POST['formName'] == "addUser") {

   if ( ($_POST['frmSurname'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmEmail'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmPassword1'] != '') ) {


    if ($_POST['frmPassword1'] != $_POST['frmPassword2'] )  {

        echo "Passwords do not match!";

//Clean form values
$cleanFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmName']);
$cleanSurname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmSurname']);
$cleanEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmEmail']);

//Clean password
$password   = sha1(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,      $_POST['frmPassword1']));

// Build username
$username       =      strtolower($cleanFirstName.substr($cleanSurname,0,1));
$dateTime       = date('Y-m-d g:i:s',time());


// Check email is unique
$QryEmail = "SELECT  *
            FROM    registeredUsers
            WHERE   EmailAddress  = '$cleanEmail'";

$chkEmail = mysqli_query($db,$QryEmail);

$numChkRowsE = mysqli_num_rows($chkEmail); 

// Check Username is unique
$QryID = "SELECT  *
        FROM    registeredUsers
        WHERE    UserName = '$username'";

$ChkID = mysqli_query($db,$QryID);

$numChkRowsI = mysqli_num_rows($chkID); 

//check that zero records returned (no duplicates)
if ($numChkRowsE == 0 && $numChkRowsI == 0){

//Query
$query = "INSERT INTO registeredUsers VALUES(NULL, '$username', '$cleanFirstName', '$cleanSurname', '$cleanEmail', '$password', '$dateTime', 0) ";

$insQry = mysqli_query($db,$query);

if ($insQry) { 
             /* SUCCESS */ 
             $_SESSION['success'] = 'Registration successful';
             header("Location:project-users-manage.php");
             exit;
        } else {
             /* FAIL */ 

        }
     }
    }   
?>

<fieldset style =width:30%>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>
        First Name :    <input type="text"     name="frmName"    value="" placeholder='First Name'><br>
        Surname: <input type="text" name="frmSurname"  value="" placeholder='Surname'><br>
        Email Address:    <input type="text"     name="frmEmail"     value="" placeholder='Email Address'><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="frmPassword1"  value="" placeholder='Password'><br>
        Repeat Password: <input type="password" name="frmPassword2"  value="" placeholder='Password Again'><br>
        <input type="submit"   name="Register"       value="Register">
        <input type='hidden' name='formName' value='addUser' />
    </p>
</form>

<br>
    <a href='project-users-manage.php'>User Management</a>
    <a href=''>Logout</a>
```

Comment: This code has a number of problems: manual escaping of user data instead of using prepared statements+placeholders, doing separate select/insert queries leading to race conditions, assuming queries rarely fail and not checking for error conditions, insert query with no fields specified leaving open the door for future breakage if the table structure ever changes. done any basic debugging, like `echo $query` to see what the sql you generated looks like?

Comment: I've got it working now. I know i need to do data validation, etc.